# New unity user, issue with Library\PackageCache\com.unity.services.core@1.11

Tags: unity-game-engine

Not really sure what to say about reproducing, im working on a small mobile game with a friend and we have this issue:

Library\PackageCache\com.unity.services.core@1.11.0\Runtime\Telemetry\Handlers\MetricsHandler.cs(20,23): error CS0308: The non-generic method 'AotHelper.EnsureType()' cannot be used with type arguments

I have tried backing up and deleting library but that did not solve the issue, also tried importing a older version of unity.services.core but nope, if anyone knows anything about this I'd be so grateful, thank you!

Comment: We need more information. What Unity version is it? Is it alpha, beta, final? Are you using Unity services? Are you logged in? How is the error triggered? Is it a compilation error or is it a playing error? Is it during a build or during PlayMode in the Editor? Do you call that function or does another library/assembly/utility? What is the code that triggers it? We can't help you without details. Your post is along the lines of "my car shows me this indicator blinking on the dashboard, what is wrong with my car?" without telling us anything about the car, how you drive it or anything else.